# Redirect a urls domain but not it's ending (ending meaning /index.html)

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'll show you what i mean.
So let's say i had the url www.url1.com and I changed the domain to www.url2.com
but there are links to my website on a ton of other sites that still go to url1.com/post/12345678 and url1.com/post/91029323, etc. I still own both domains, but i need url1.com/post/1 and url1.com/post/9 to redirect to url**2**.com/post/1 and url**2**.com/post/9 instead.

Do you get what I'm saying?

Now these aren't really websites these are blogs hosted by tumblr but same difference.
I think I have the code figured out, but it just doesn't seem to work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       function myFunction()
        {
        var permalink = document.URL;
        var newlink = permalink.replace("url1","url2");
        window.location.replace(newlink);
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
        come ooon redirect already
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason it works in the previews while editing the blogs theme (its an iframe next to the html code(tumblr thing)), but not on the blog itself.

And if there is a way easier way to do it (please javascript jquery only (unless it's html or css (probably not css)) everything else never works for me) please tell me i'm oblivious sometimes
Thank's ahead of time.

Comment: What do you mean by preview? Can you link us to an example? Also, try just using window.location()

Comment: @danL `window.location()`? It's not a function

Comment: Sorry, I meant window.location.href - it's been a long night haha

Comment: @danL I tried window.location.href and it didn't work, by preview i mean like an iframe that is right next to the code your editing that shows you what the code ends up looking like, and this is the blog I'm redirecting from: http://fewobsessionsofmine.tumblr.com/

Comment: http://tumblring.net/tumblr-redirects/

Comment: @SalmanA: With meta refresh tag it is only possible for static URLs, isn't it? Correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: If you're saying that, for example, meta refresh cannot be used to change _portion_ of URL then you are right. OP might need to manually set new redirect URL for each post. The plus side is that some search engines treat a 0 second refresh as a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
window.location = newlink;
```